# Libreoffice : Getting cell value from a range referring to another range

Tags: libreoffice-calc

i have a row '1'  of minutes ( 1,2,3,4,5 ..) and below a   row  '2'  of values ( 10,50,5,60,9..). How  to get the minute of the greater value  in cell C2 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX(A1:F1;MATCH(MAX(A2:F2);A2:F2;0))
```

Make sure to change the three `F` to whatever column your rows extend to.

The `MAX` finds the greatest value in row 2.

Then the `MATCH` finds the column number of that value in row 2 - note the last field in the `MATCH` formula is `0` indicating the list is unsorted and you are looking for an exact match.

The `INDEX` looks up the row 1 value in the column number returned by the `MATCH`.